# Upgrade to Weblogic 12c and using jaxws 2.1

Tags: java, web-services, service

Could you please explain if someone have occurred the following situation?
I have upgraded the application server from Weblogic 10.0 to Weblogic 12c.
Also I have generated a webservice using the jaxws client provided by weblogic12 and now the xml contains a namespace duplicated but differs the prefix.`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`.

I have started to think that the problem is related to the upgrade from weblogic 10 to weblogic12 because the new webservice that was regenerated it's working ok in weblogic10.

your help will be apreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add this after you have created the Header and it should resolve the problem, I was able to close the issue at my end
**header.setPrefix(envelope.getPrefix());**

The code can be changed to

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart()
                        .getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
if( header == null ){
    envelope.addHeader();
    header = envelope.getHeader();
}
header.setPrefix(envelope.getPrefix());
```